# strict topology on multiplier algebras

Tags: gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra,$M(A)$ is the multiplier algebra.If $S$ is a subset of $M(A)$ which is compact for the strict topology on $M(A)$,is $S$ also a subset of $M(M(A))$ which is compact for the strict topology on $M(M(A))$?

Comment: If $B$ is a unital algebra then $M(B) = B$.  So surely $M(M(A)) = M(A)$?  Or did you mean something else by this notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I understand the question, you are asking this:  Let $S$ be a subset of $M(A)$ which is compact for the strict topology.  (The strict topology is such that a net $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ exactly when $x_ia\rightarrow xa, ax_i\rightarrow ax$ in norm, for each $a\in A$).  Now set $B=M(A)$, a unital algebra, and consider $M(B)$, which is just $B$.  We also consider the strict on $M(B)=B$, which is just the norm topology (let $a=1$ in the above description).  Is $S \subseteq B$ also compact in the strict (=norm) topology.

So, in short:

> Let $S$ be a subset of $M(A)$ which is compact for the strict topology.  Is $S$ also compact for the norm topology on $M(A)$?

As you might expect, the answer is "no".  For a counter-example, let $A=K(H)$ the compact operators on a separable Hilbert space with basis $(e_n)$, and let $t_n(\xi) = (\xi | e_n) e_n$ be the rank-one projection onto the span of $(e_n)$.  Then $t_n =t_n^*$ and $t_n(\xi)\rightarrow 0$ for each $\xi\in H$, and $(t_n)$ is bounded.  It follows that $t_n\rightarrow 0$ in the strict topology on $M(A) = B(H)$.  Set
$$ S = \{ t_n : n\geq 1 \} \cup \{0\}. $$
It follows that $S$ is compact in $M(A)$.  However, as a subset of $B(H)$ with the norm topology, $S$ is not compact.

Comment: @mathrookie The strict topology on a unital C$^*$-algebra is the norm topology, and $M(A)$ is unital, whether $A$ is or not. I am a bit baffled by your second sentence, because the whole point of Matthew Daws's answer is to show that the strict topology on $M(A)$ and $M(M(A))$ are different.